# How would I power a circuit and charge its battery simultaneously?

Tags: transistors, battery-charging, solid-state-relay

I have a circuit powered by a rechargeable battery. When a USB cable is plugged in, I want the battery to charge through a separate charging circuit and for the main circuit to be powered through the USB cable and not the battery. I know there are dedicated ICs for this but am curious if it can be done otherwise.

Here's what I have so far. VSUPPLY (below the battery connector) is the voltage input to the main circuit. VBATT+ is connected to VSUPPLY through solid state relay K2 unless VCHARGE (i.e. VUSB) is present, in which case VCHARGE is connected to VSUPPLY instead. VCHARGE is also connected to VBATT+ through solid state relay K1, under normal charging conditions. D2 is to ensure nothing powers the charging circuit when the USB cable is not plugged in.

Does this effectively prevent the battery from powering the main circuit while it's charging?

[image]

Comment: Your schematic seems to be cut off on the left.

Comment: It can be done but it is a pain in the ass. Usually you will want the switch between battery and load to drop very little power because the load or part of it is a 3.3V regulator. So you can't just use a diode. You have to use a MOSFET.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might be able to achieve what I'm going for by putting D1 between pins 3 and 4 of K1 and K2, respectively, such that current only ever flows into the battery at the connection to VCHARGE.

Answer (score 0):

There are many IC’s that do this better and some for 0.31$ (1) https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Skyworks%20PDFs/AAT3683.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to put one diode forward in the battery rail and another one in the USB rail, conneted in the positive side.

Assuming the battery voltage around 3.7V, when you have 5V in the usb rail then in V1 you have almost 5V (minus voltage drop of D1) and D2 is reverse biased so cut off, as the voltage of the battery is lower.
When there is no voltage in the USB rail then D2 let the current flow.
[image]

The disadvantage is the voltage drop of the D2 diode, you loose it from the battery range. Then another option is to use a P-channel mosfet instead of the diode in the battery rail, with the gate connected to the USB rail. So, the mosfet only conducts when the voltage in the USB rail is lower than in the battery rail. Something like this, with a mosfet with low voltage drop.
[image]